# Cannot Post in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm making my first steps into Angular, so I decided to start with a CRUD.

I've been doing this following a guide, but I got crashed into a concrete wall, as I've checked everything and couldn't find a solution.

I'm trying to create a **Project** (model), which has **3 columns**:

- Title
- Description (Nullable)
- AccessCode (Nullable)

I need to make a POST request to add the data into my database (Backed by Node.js and working fine from Postman)

This is the code I have:

**add-project-component.ts**

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    Project
} from 'src/app/models/project.model';
import {
    ProjectService
} from 'src/app/services/project.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-project',
    templateUrl: './add-project.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-project.component.css']
})
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {

    project: Project = {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        accessCode: '',
    };
    submitted = false;

    constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    saveProject(): void {
        const data = {
            title: this.project.title,
            description: this.project.description,
            accessCode: this.project.accessCode
        };

        this.projectService.create(data)
            .subscribe({
                next: (res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.submitted = true;
                },
                error: (e) => console.error(e)
            });
    }

    newProject(): void {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.project = {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            accessCode: ''
        };
    }

}
```

**add-project-component.html**

```
<div class="new-project">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <span>New Project</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content *ngIf="!submitted">
            <p>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                    <input id="title" required [(ngModel)]="project.title" matInput name="title" placeholder="Title">
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <p>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                    <textarea id="description" rows="6" [(ngModel)]="project.description" name="description" matInput placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <p>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Access Code</mat-label>
                    <input id="accessCode" [(ngModel)]="project.accessCode" name="accessCode" matInput placeholder="Access Code">
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
        <!-- FORM CONTENT -->
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions *ngIf="!submitted">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="newProject()">Create Project</button>
         <!-- REGISTER BUTTON -->
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

**services/project.service.ts**

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Project } from '../models/project.model';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/projects';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(baseUrl);
  }

  get(id: any): Observable<Project> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }

  update(id: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(baseUrl);
  }

  findByTitle(title: any): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(`${baseUrl}?title=${title}`);
  }
}
```

**Error 404**

[image]

Can you guys help me out? What am I missing?
Thank you very much.

Comment: there is no information about the 'cannot post' part

Comment: Did you mean to do `(click)="saveProject()"` instead of `(click)="newProject()"` on your Create Project button?

Comment: I've changed newProject() to SaveProject() and it finally gave me an error. Now I'm getting this error: 

"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/projects</pre>
</body>
</html>
"

Seems like the route where the API es getting the POST request is not the same as Angular thinks. How can I change it?

Comment: What's the route that you tried through postman? How does the service method look like in your frontend?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner The route I used in Postman was localhost:8080/api/projects/create, while in my app-routing module I have this: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsListComponent },
  { path: 'projects/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: AddProjectComponent }
];

Comment: The API route has nothing to do with the routes defined in your angular-app. If anything you need to edit the route that you want to `post` to in your `ProjectsService#create` function.

Comment: I've done some research but I couldn't find anything related :( Could you please give me a bit more information about it? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you provide the project.service code? @DavidEncinaMartínez

Comment: @HosseinSalmanian const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/projects';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(baseUrl);
  }

  get(id: any): Observable<Project> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }

  findByTitle(title: any): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(`${baseUrl}?title=${title}`);
  }
}

Comment: @DavidEncinaMartínez it`s not a good idea to post sample code in comments.
please add the service code to your question.

Comment: is there any error at runtime?

Comment: It seems nothing is wrong related with Angular.
You said api address is http://localhost:8080/api/projects/create, but in your service you have send the request to http://localhost:8080/api/projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create` function points to the wrong URL.
Your desired URL is `/api/projects/create`, but you are missing the `/create` part.

Change

```
create(data: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
}
```

to

```
create(data: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/create`, data);
}
```

given that `const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/projects';` is correct.
Note: For production you most likely want to change `baseUrl` to
`const baseUrl = '/api/projects';` as the host will change (`localhost` vs your actual domain).